# Ways to open a corrupted .avi?

Tags: video, file-formats

I recorded some game footage using MSI afterburner and accidentally closed afterburner before stopping the recording and now I can't open the resulting file. MPC, VLC, Sony Vegas can't open it. MPC says "cannot render the file" others just don't react. The size of the file is 150Gb which is what I would expect. I want to extract/convert the data from the file somehow so that I can edit it in Sony Vegas. What should I try?

I tried using bandi-fix. It says that the file is not an avi file.

My MSI Afterburner settings :

[image: msi settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with repairing avi files is that in your case you used Motion JPEG compression not H264. Motion JPEG requires an ending bit of code at the end of the file. H264 builds the video in blocks and if the video is cut off then only the last block is bad and thus lost. The only way that I have found that may yield a result is opening it in a video editor, throwing it into a timeline and cutting off the end and re rendering it out into a new file. This doesn't always work as most editors won't import the file, but it is worth a try. The short answer is that if this does not work then you are probably out of luck. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: If an editor could open it there would have been no problem. But thanks for the insight on how mjpg works.